# Apple ID on apps

Tags: ipad, applications, apple-id

So my iPad in setup to my newest Apple id. Every time I try to enter an app like Facebook it asks me for my old Apple id that I don't use anymore. I can't enter the apps without it. Does anyone know what to do? Thank you.

Comment: Delete all the apps you've previously downloaded from the older account. Download them from the new Apple ID!